# DiskCache non-image files without checking directory

Tags: imageresizer

I'm using ImageResizer to resize profile pictures (uploaded by users) on the fly. The profile pictures are stored with the filename being their ID, and without an extension. They are also in a directory that contains other files uploaded by users that may not be images. I reference the file in my cshtml file using something like this:

```html
<img src="//localhost:34754/8FF479AC7724A82A001603EF1566A7EFD852D35561BC2E14B1A01D99CEC035C7F265A3FF7F2642098DD2999217EC7A94?width=100" />
```

I want ImageResizer to know not to ignore this request, even though it doesn't have an image extension. I found this page: http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/cache-non-images

This describes how to solve an issue similar to mine, except it requires specifying a directory. But I don't want ImageResizer to handle all requests from this directory, since there are non-images stored there as well. Is there some other way I can tell ImageResizer not to ignore the URL? Maybe by adding something to the query string? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample event handler uses a directory and a file extension as an example; you are free to use a querystring key or any other kind of indicator as you wish; it's just an example.

```
Config.Current.Pipeline.PostAuthorizeRequestStart += delegate(IHttpModule sender2, HttpContext context) {
  var query = Config.Current.Pipeline.ModifiedQueryString;

  if (query["flag"] != "true") return;

  Config.Current.Pipeline.SkipFileTypeCheck = true; //Skip the file extension check. 

  //Non-images will be served as-is
  //Cache all file types, whether they are processed or not.
  Config.Current.Pipeline.ModifiedQueryString["cache"] = ServerCacheMode.Always.ToString();
};
```